# Avoiding "Failed to expand shell folder constant userdocs" errors in Inno Setup

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup

I install some sample documents into a 'PerfectTablePlan' sub-folder of the standard 'My documents' folder on Windows. This works fine for 99%+ of users. But if a user doesn't have a 'My documents' folder I get a number of ugly error messages of the form:

> Internal error:Failed to expand shell folder constant “userdocs”

This is not very confidence inspiring for the user!

It is acceptable to not install the samples for these users (or install them somewhere else). But not to show the ugly error messages.

The problem seems to come from the ExpandConstant macro expansion of {userdocs}.

Is there some way I can get the path of 'My documents' without using a macro?

Or some way to suppress the error message? ExpandConstant throws an exception:
http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_expandconstant

The relevant parts of my .iss file looks like this:

```
#define MySampleDir "{code:SampleDirRoot}\PerfectTablePlan"
...
[Files]
Source: ..\binaries\windows\program\plans\*_v14.tp; DestDir: {#MySampleDir}\; Flags: ignoreversion onlyifdoesntexist createallsubdirs recursesubdirs uninsneveruninstall;
Source: ..\binaries\windows\program\plans\*_v3.tps; DestDir: {#MySampleDir}\; Flags: ignoreversion onlyifdoesntexist createallsubdirs recursesubdirs uninsneveruninstall;
...
[Code]
function SampleDirRoot(Param: String): String;
begin
if DirExists( ExpandConstant('{userdocs}') ) then
Result := ExpandConstant('{userdocs}')
else
Result := ExpandConstant('{allusersprofile}')
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception:

> Failed to expand shell folder constant 'constant name'

is raised when the internally called [`SHGetFolderPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function (called from inside `ExpandConstant` when expanding a shell folder constant) returns an empty path string for the given folder CSIDL, in this case for the [`CSIDL_PERSONAL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#CSIDL_PERSONAL) identifier.

That means the user doesn't have the [`CSIDL_PERSONAL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#CSIDL_PERSONAL) folder. It makes me wonder how can one configure Windows' user account to not have that folder. Well, you can workaround this issue (or Windows misconfiguration ?) by catching the raised internal exception in the `try..except` block:

```
[Code]
function SampleDirRoot(Param: string): string;
var
  Folder: string;
begin
  try
    // first try to expand the {userdocs} folder; if this raises that
    // internal exception, you'll fall down to the except block where
    // you expand the {allusersprofile}
    Folder := ExpandConstant('{userdocs}');
    // the {userdocs} folder expanding succeded, so let's test if the
    // folder exists and if not, expand {allusersprofile}
    if not DirExists(Folder) then
      Folder := ExpandConstant('{allusersprofile}');
  except
    Folder := ExpandConstant('{allusersprofile}');
  end;
  // return the result
  Result := Folder;
end;
```

But I've never heard about possibility of not having the [`CSIDL_PERSONAL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#CSIDL_PERSONAL) folder. Please note, that the above code protects only the `{userdocs}` constant.

Comment: Some IT people seem to configure work computers without a 'My documents' folder. Presumably to force them to store documents on a network drive.

Comment: I've been searching for some advice on this, but couldn't find anything. That makes me wonder what other folders they can disable that way. One should worry to expand any non-system constant then. However, it's correct that it raises exception because there is no other output from `ExpandConstant`. Maybe some sort of `TryExpandConstant` function would be handy. It would return boolean if expanding succeeded, and the expanded value would return to the output parameter.

Comment: Or maybe just a flag to suppress the error message?

Comment: I will try your fix and report back.

Comment: That would have to be global somehow. And what would the function return ? If an empty string e.g., how would you determine that the expanding failed (note, that some constants may intentionally return empty string, e.g. the `{code...}` one) ? Try it, I'm sure it's the only workaround to protect `ExpandConstant` ([`source`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_5/Projects/Main.pas#L1145)). Another option would be calling `GetShellFolder` just like Inno Setup internally does, and check if the function returned empty string. The `GetShellFolder` function does not raise exception.

Comment: GetShellFolder should also work: http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_getshellfolder

Comment: Yes, that's why I mentioned it in my last comment :)

Comment: Every time I delete 'My documents' it reappears. So I don't know how to test this!

Comment: Neither me. But the `InternalError` function only [`raises exception`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_5/Projects/InstFunc.pas#L123) to the script. And for catching exceptions in script there's the `try..except` block, so I'm sure what I've posted is a correct workaround to protect the `ExpandConstant` function call for that constant.

Comment: If you want to test whether the `try..except` block catches the `InternalError`, you can simply try to [`extract a not existing file`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_5/Projects/Install.pas#L3093). Just note, that if you'll run your script through debugger with *Pause on exception* IDE option enabled, you'll get an exception dialog raised before the code continues.

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible to actually remove the My Documents folder as it is a Shell folder. However, it is possible to use Folder Redirection to change its location using Group Policy. A lot of IT admins will do this to redirect it to a network location, so that data is not stored locally (as you observe) to ensure it is included in a backup. Could it be that Folder Redirection is causing the exception i.e. that it is expecting a local path, but is receiving a network (UNC) path instead, rather than the folder actually having been removed?

Comment: Note, in my experience, Folder Redirection causes many unexpected results and is best avoided. Unfortunately, if it is due to this, I'm not sure how or if this helps you handle the exception. Hopefully it might be useful extra information though.

Comment: @Robert, the problem here was that if you try to expand a folder constant that the system doesn't know for some reason (in the end it is the `SHGetFolderPath` WinAPI function that returns empty path string), an [`exception is raised`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_5/Projects/Main.pas#L1145). Hence the workaround in this post is catching (any) exception that can be raised during expand attempt providing fallback to a different folder. So it was about *empty* (undefined ?) path and exception that is raised if it's *empty*, not about UNC.

Comment: I missed the fact that the exception was being thrown due to it being empty and was looking for an explanation as to why it was throwing an exception. It doesn't explain why it is empty though, as it shouldn't be possible.

Comment: This happened for me when "My Documents" pointed to a network drive. The installer is running with elevated privileges which is technically another user session, and it didn't have that drive connected because network drives are connected per-session. According to http://www.winability.com/how-to-make-elevated-programs-recognize-network-drives/ , this can be fixed by setting `HKLM/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Policies/System|EnableLinkedConnections=0x1`. It can be fixed temporarily by opening an elevated command prompt, connecting network drives in it and keeping it open.

Comment: I'd like to add a few lines on this regarding my experience. I got this error during the execution my application which installs some software packed using Inno Setup over a local network under a domain. 
In order to perform the installation, my application uses WMI and impersonates the domain administrator which has full rights on every computer of the domain, but does not necessarily have its own user folder created on them. When the installer tries to expand constants on the user subfolders this exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

We use folder redirection here and have had issues similar to this with other apps (GnuCash, UFile). The problem in our case was a result of a feature called Redirected Folder Migration*, which in some cases did not update the user's registry settings to point to the new location after the migration was completed (note this migration might occur weeks after the GPO was set).

Anyway, it's not that the entry was blank, but that it pointed to a SERVER\SHARE that had been brought offline weeks earlier.

Running a `gpupdate /force` for every active user on every machine fixed our problem, as it updated the registry and then told the user he had to logoff / logon.

---

*Redirected Folder Migration allows an admin to specify that each user's (e.g.) My Documents folder should be moved from one network location to another. It does this in a slow, measured fashion, the next time the user logs on to (any workstation on) the domain (so if your last user only logs on a month from now, the process takes a month to complete). It's a lovely idea in theory, but in practice is a big PITA.

Incidentally, the *'share doesn't exist because it's impersonating another user'* thing shouldn't be an issue with properly redirected folders because the redirect should use a URL, not a mapped drive letter (e.g. \\server\RedirectedUserFolders\SOME-USER\My Documents, although permissions might be an issue if you remove some default rights).