# DOCKER installation ERROR "Internal error: Failed to expand shell folder constant "userdocs" on Windows

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-machine, docker-toolbox

I am trying to install the docker toolbox on Window 8.1 Enterprise , but getting the following error.

[image: Installation Error]

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to [issue 435](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/435), which is followed by a pending [PR 441](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/pull/441)

> Change replaces '`userdocs`' variable usage with '`userappdata`' to account for users with '`My Documents`' locations which are not the default windows location.

(`userdocs` is currently used in [`windows/Toolbox.iss#L239-L244`](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/blob/fcdf7c37950dab9658556b1566b4363fa930878b/windows/Toolbox.iss#L239-L244))

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: 
-Open SystemControl->System->Advanced Settings->Environment Settings
-add new Key "USERDOCS" pointing to a valid Path
-restart the installer completely to activate the var

Answer (score 0):

As per [Q28635548](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28635548/1418999), for my case (working on a virtualized domain Windows 7 client) it helped to use `regedit` to (temporarily) modify the 
`[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders]` registry key with name `Personal` into a directory that is currently available (e.g. some local path when if you're currently disconnected from the domain)